# CUDA code fails to enter while loop

Tags: c, cuda

I'm trying to run a paralle BFS algorithm on CUDA

This is my kernel code

```
__global__ void initialize_vertices(int* vertices, int starting_vertex){

    int v = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if( v == starting_vertex){
        vertices[v] = 0;        
    }else{
        vertices[v] = -1;
    } 
}

__global__ void bfs(const Edge* edges, int* vertices, int* current_depth, bool* done){

    int e = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    int vfirst = edges[e].first;
    int dfirst = vertices[vfirst];
    int vsecond = edges[e].second;
    int dsecond = vertices[vsecond];

    if((dfirst == *current_depth) && (dsecond == -1)){
        vertices[vsecond] = dfirst +1;
        *current_depth = dfirst+1;
        *done = false;
    }
    if((dsecond == *current_depth) && (dfirst == -1)){
        vertices[vfirst] = dsecond + 1;
        *current_depth = dsecond +1;
        *done = false;
    }
}
```

Here's my definition of the struct Edge

```
typedef struct Edge
{
    int first;
    int second;

}Edge;
```

This is the main where both the kernels are called.

```
int main(int argc, char** argv){

    const int NUM_VERTICES = 10000;
    const size_t VERTEX_BYTES = NUM_VERTICES * sizeof(int);
    const int NUM_EDGES = 10000;
    const size_t EDGE_BYTES = NUM_EDGES * sizeof(Edge);
    const int STARTING_VERTEX = 25;
    cudaError_t err = cudaSuccess;

    //declare the two arrays on host
    int h_vertices[NUM_VERTICES];
    Edge h_edges[NUM_EDGES];


    //fill up the edges array
    for (int i = 0; i < NUM_EDGES; ++i)   
    {
        h_edges[i].first = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
        h_edges[i].second = (rand() % (NUM_VERTICES+1));
    }

    //define the two arrays on the device
    Edge* d_edges;
    int* d_vertices;

    //Allocate memory on device for both arrays
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_edges, EDGE_BYTES);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate edges array on device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_vertices, VERTEX_BYTES);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate vertices array on device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }


    err = cudaMemcpy(d_edges, h_edges, EDGE_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy edges array from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    err = cudaMemcpy(d_vertices, h_vertices, VERTEX_BYTES, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy vertices array from host to device (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //assign thread configuration
    int threadsPerBlock = 512;
    int blocksPerGrid =(NUM_VERTICES + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    printf("CUDA kernel launch with %d blocks of %d threads\n", blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock);

    initialize_vertices<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(d_vertices, STARTING_VERTEX);
    err = cudaGetLastError();
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to launch initialization kernel (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    printf("Initialization completed\n");
    bool h_done = true;
    bool* d_done;

    int h_current_depth = 0;
    int* d_current_depth;

    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_done, sizeof(bool));
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocte d_done(error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    err = cudaMalloc((void**)&d_current_depth, sizeof(int));
    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to allocate d_current_depth(error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }
    //printf("Reached here\n");

    while(!h_done){
        printf("Entered while loop\n");
        err = cudaMemcpy(d_done, &h_done, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy h_done to device(error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        err = cudaMemcpy(d_current_depth, &h_current_depth, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to launch copy h_current_depth to kernel(error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        printf("CUDA kernel launch with %d blocks of %d threads\n", blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock);

        bfs<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>(h_edges, h_vertices, d_current_depth, d_done);
        //cudaThreadsSynchronize();
        err = cudaGetLastError();
        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to launch bfs kernel (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        err = cudaMemcpy(&h_done, d_done, sizeof(bool), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy d_done to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        err = cudaMemcpy(&h_current_depth, d_current_depth, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        if (err != cudaSuccess)
        {
            fprintf(stderr, "Failed to copy d_current_depth to host (error code %s)!\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

    }
    //printf("Breadth first traversal completed over %d levels\n", h_current_depth);
    cudaFree(d_edges);
    cudaFree(d_vertices);
    //cudaFree(d_done);
    //cudaFree(d_current_depth);
    err = cudaDeviceReset();

    if (err != cudaSuccess)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Failed to deinitialize the device! error=%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(err));
        exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
    }

    printf("Done\n");

    return 0;

}
```

The code compiles fine, but somehow the thread of execution just never enters the while loop to launch the second kernel.
I'm new to CUDA, can someone help me with the issue here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is really straight-forward and has absolutely nothing to do with CUDA. You perhaps overlooked this issue or are not familiar with the concept of `while` loop. Stripped down version of your code:

```
bool h_done = true;
// ...
while(!h_done){
    // ...
}
```

Because `h_done` is `true` you really cannot expect the `while` loop ever to be entered. `!h_done == false`, i.e. the condition of the `while` loop is always `false`. Such trivial issue would be discovered in a no time if you use the debugger.

However, there might be plenty other problems in your code, but I cant tell as you haven't provided a working example, e.g. definition of class `Edge`.

Comment: Apologies, fixed that part added Edge definition.

Comment: @Antithesis alright, the code now compiles. Based on that I can say my above answer is correct - you have either false expectations towards how the `while` loops work or have overlooked that `!h_done` is `false`.

Comment: I've accepted your answer, but would really appreciate if you can help me as to why the memcpy inside the while loop is failing.

Comment: memcpy is defined as memcpy(dst, src, size, direction). You using a host destination ptr on some cudamemcpy but specifying direction as cudaMemcpyHostToDevice. It should be cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost.